# AUTO INCREMENT NUMBERs into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if someone can help me out.  I am creating a simple script where I want to auto increment a number into a field with the number being lead by 7 0's.

Example: 00000001

Here is my script: its a small update script

```
DECLARE @EDI NVARCHAR(55)
SET @EDI=0000000
UPDATE TESTER11111
SET @EDI=EDI=@EDI+1
WHERE ssq='education'
```

instead of incrementing the numbers as 00000001, 00000002.
its incrementing as 1, 2, 3, etc.

what am I doing wrong?  how can i insert those leading 7 0's?

EDI is the column that I am inserting the increments.

Comment: What is the datatype of EDI in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the table increment (and just store integers), but there's no reason I can think of not to go ahead and format on the select statement; a fixed number format is as much data as business logic

```
 SELECT Right(Replicate('0',8)+Convert(nvarchar(8),EDI),8)
```

**EDIT**: if you must save the formatted values:

```
DECLARE @EDI NVARCHAR(55) 
SET @EDI=0
UPDATE TESTER11111 
SET @EDI=EDI=Right(Replicate('0',8)+Convert(nvarchar(8),@EDI+1),8) 
WHERE ssq='education'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't. As far as the database is concerned 01 is the same as 1.  If you wan't leading zeros, you will have to construct a string, padded with zeros, when you pull the data from the database.

**EDIT**

Normally I would do the formatting in the application, but there are times when I have to do it in the database.  Here is an example, there might be a better solution in newer versions, but this is what I use.

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(5, 8), ' ', '0')
```

Comment: Exactly - a database stores data.  Formatting is done in the UI.

Comment: @ck (and various other UI-only commenters) while I don't think the format should be persisted to a table column, I'm at a loss to see how this example is "just" formatting. What's the use case for these ID values being used _without_ format?

Comment: @downwitch, the use case is that you want to use the id value to uniquely identify a record.  It doesn't matter if your program asks for record 001 or 1, because they are the same value you will get the same record.  What the user wants is kind of like asking the system to do `1 + 1` and return `TWO`. "TWO" might be a useful way to present 2 to a user, but it is unrelated to how a computer internally represents the number 2, which is the same as how it represents 02.  How would the system know if you want to format 2 as 002 or "TWO"?  You have to format the number to suit your application.

Comment: @downwitch, also, it is much slower to index and retrieve a string than a number. Using the string `"00000001"` as an index, when you can use the number `1` is a very bad idea.

Comment: I suppose I can get behind the index/retrieve idea, though it would take a LOT of records to see that difference. But it's not clear that this is a unique-identifier field, is it? (And yeah, I know I called it one too.)

Answer (score 3):

Have your "regular" `INT IDENTITY` column in your table, and have a computed column that handles the additional work:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.IDTest
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  FormattedID AS RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED
)
```

Now, your table will contain values such as:

```
ID     FormattedID
  1     00000001
  2     00000002
 ..
 42     00000042
 ..
123     00000123
```

This computed column is persisted, e.g. you can also index it, if need be.

Comment: Pretty snazzy, still think it's not really something to do in the DB, but if you had to this is pretty cool.

Comment: @invertedSpear: yes, it really shouldn't be in the database in the first place - but if you absolutely have to have it stored, this is the best way to go in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

This is better handled in your business logic (php, asp, coldfusion or whatever). Incrementing works on integers, not strings. Else it would have to go through the whole alphabet.

Answer (score -1):

**try This**

```
UPDATE TESTER11111
SET @EDI='0000000'+''+1
WHERE ssq='education'
```

> **Select '0000000'++(Auto number)**
>
> O/P
>   00000001